# Add missing newlines in multiple files

Tags: bash, awk, newline, text-files

I have a bunch of files that are incomplete: the last line is missing an *EOL* character.

What's the easiest way to add the newline, using any tool (awk maybe?)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10082204/add-a-newline-only-if-it-doesnt-exist

Answer (score 33, accepted):

To add a newline at the end of a file:

```
echo >>file
```

To add a line at the end of every file in the current directory:

```
for x in *; do echo >>"$x"; done
```

If you don't know in advance whether each file ends in a newline, test the last character first. `tail -c 1` prints the last character of a file. Since command substitution truncates any final newline, `$(tail -c 1 <file)` is empty if the file is empty or ends in a newline, and non-empty if the file ends in a non-newline character.

```
for x in *; do if [ -n "$(tail -c 1 <"$x")" ]; then echo >>"$x"; fi; done
```

Comment: why does `tail -c 1` return nothing if the file ends in a newline?

Comment: @MuMind: `tail -c 1` always returns the last character, whether it's a newline or not. It's the shell's command substitution construct `$(…)` that strips final newlines. So if `tail -c 1` outputs just one non-newline character, you get that character. If `tail -c 1` outputs just one newline character, or nothing (empty file), you get nothing.

Comment: If you don't want to add the newline to empty files, use ...`if [ -s "$x" -a -n "$(tail -c 1 <"$x")" ]; then`...

Comment: @Gordon: No need for that extra complexity. `$(tail -c 1 <"$x")` is empty for an empty file.

Comment: You're right; I just had the conditions messed up in my head.

Comment: To do this recursively within a Git repository, I've come accross this solution (needs some patience, depending on your repository size - and also modifies binary files, I just reverted these changes): https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/161853/

Answer (score 5):

Vim is great for that because if you do not open a file in `binary` mode, it will automatically end the file with the detected line ending.

So:

```
vim file -c 'wq'
```

should work, regardless of whether your files have Unix, Windows or Mac end of line style.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo >> filename
```

Try it before mass use :)