# Add a newline only if it doesn't exist

Tags: linux, bash, sed, newline

I want to add a newline at the end of a file only if it doesn't exist. This is to prevent multiple newlines at the end of the file.

I'm hoping to use `sed`.
Here are the issues I'm having with my current code:

```
sed -i -e '/^$/d;$G' /inputfile

echo file1
name1
name2

echo file2
name3
name4
(newline)
```

when I run my code on to the files;

```
echo file1
name1
name2
(newline)

echo file2
name3
name4
```

it adds a newline if it doesn't have one but removes it if it exists... this puzzles me.

Comment: this worked for me: [unix.se/31955/11438](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/31955/11438)

Comment: This post was *[merged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158066/what-is-a-merged-question)* with [How to fix “No newline at end of file” warning for lots of files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3261925/1765658). But for working with ***A lot of files,*** the command `tee -a` should be used. See [How to add newline character at the end of many files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43281250/1765658)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since it removes newline if it's not there, you could simply use:

```
echo "" >> file;  sed -ie '/^$/d;$G' file; sed -ie '/^$/d;$G' file
```

Adds a newline and removes everything then adds newline. Not the elegant way, but certainly works :)

Comment: `echo "" >> file;`
adds a newline;
`sed -ie '/^$/d;$G' file;`
removes a newline? and apply the same code again?

EDIT: it certainly works, but i think there must be a neater way.. :P

Answer (score 44):

#### sed

GNU:

```
sed -i '$a\' *.txt
```

OS X:

```
sed -i '' '$a\' *.txt
```

`$` addresses the last line. `a\` is the append function.

#### OS X's sed

```
sed -i '' -n p *.txt
```

`-n` disables printing and `p` prints the pattern space. `p` adds a missing newline in OS X's sed but not in GNU sed, so this doesn't work with GNU sed.

#### awk

```
awk 1
```

`1` (the number one) can be replaced with anything that evaluates to true. Modifying a file in place:

```
{ rm file;awk 1 >file; }<file
```

#### bash

```
[[ $(tail -c1 file) && -f file ]]&&echo ''>>file
```

Trailing newlines are removed from the result of the command substitution, so `$(tail -c1 file)` is empty only if `file` ends with a linefeed or is empty. `-f file` is false if `file` is empty. `[[ $x ]]` is equivalent to `[[ -n $x ]]` in bash.

Comment: points for neatness!  the `$\a` formulation didn't work (on a mac), but the `-n p` one did... how does it work though?

Comment: hm, actually, trying them out on ubuntu bash, both return an error `sed: can't read p: No such file or directory`

Comment: I edited the answer. It was supposed to be `sed '$a\'`. Apparently `-i ''` doesn't work with GNU sed.

Comment: `sed -i '$a\' <files>` worked perfectly for me on Ubuntu.  Thanks!

Comment: The GNU solution works just fine on OS X El Capitan (10.11).

Comment: It's possible to use find to apply this to all files in a directory (and subdirectories). Ex : `find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i '' -e '$a\'`

Comment: The bash answer is very helpful to me.  however one issue I run into is that if I place it in a bash script, it produces a non-zero return code if the blank line exists which is throwing errors if used in ansible.

Comment: for Bash to avoid failure on non-zero returns (for example, by `set -e`), do: `[[ ! -f file || -z $(tail -c1 file) ]] || echo >>file` (If file doesn't exist, then don't add a leading newline OR if the last char of file is a newline, then don't add a newline; otherwise, add a newline)

Comment: the globbing doesn't work for me on os x, i can only do it for each file individually

Comment: neither `sed -i '' '$a\'` nor `sed -i '' -n p` are working for me on os x 13.4 stock `sed`.

Answer (score 16):

Rather than processing the whole file with `sed` just to add a newline at the end, just check the last character and if it's *not* a newline, append one.  Testing for newline is slightly interesting, since the shell will generally trim them from the end of strings, so I append "x" to protect it:

```
if [ "$(tail -c1 "$inputfile"; echo x)" != $'\nx' ]; then
    echo "" >>"$inputfile"
fi
```

Note that this will append newline to empty files, which might not be what you want.  If you want to leave empty files alone, add another test:

```
if [ -s "$inputfile" ] && [ "$(tail -c1 "$inputfile"; echo x)" != $'\nx' ]; then
    echo "" >>"$inputfile"
fi
```

Comment: nice and clean in that it only requires tail and echo, rather than sed or awk.

Answer (score 11):

Converted Norman's answer to a split one-liner for convenience.

```
for i in * ; do  echo $i; \
 if diff /dev/null "$i" | tail -1 | \
  grep '^\\ No newline' > /dev/null; then echo >> "$i"; \
 fi; done
```

Replace * with whatever file pattern you want, eg `*.c`

And another to just tell you which files are broken:

```
for i in * ; do \
 if diff /dev/null "$i" | tail -1 | \
  grep '^\\ No newline' > /dev/null; then  echo $i; \
 fi; done
```

Comment: If you want it to go recursively, you can swap `*` with `$(find . -type f)` or `$(find <dirname> -type f -name <filepattern>)`

Answer (score 9):

A simple fix for files that are "missing" newline at end of file is simply sed; the following fixes the file "in-place" (using the "-i" option):

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i -e '$a\' {} \; -print
```

**Explanation:**

- find all files (`-type f`),
- run `sed`,
- change the files in-place (`-i`),
- given the following (`-e`) script/expression, which matches the end of the file (`$`),

  - and perform the "append" action (`a\`),
  - but don't actually specify any text to append (nothing after the `\`) which is going to add a newline to the end of the file, but only if it's missing.
- Prints all files found (fixed or not), which is probably unnecessary.

Main caveat is that `sed` features vary across platforms, so `-i` and `-e` may or may not be supported / the same; e.g. older Unix, or MacOS oddities may require slightly different syntax.

To only operate on filename(s) matching specific suffix(es), just add `find path/to/dir -type f \( -name \*.C -o -name \*.h -o -name \*.java \) -exec ...`

Comment: **Warning:** Do ***not*** do this at the root of a Git repo without adding a `-prune` or `-not -name` to the `find` command to omit the `.git/` directory. Otherwise, you'll corrupt it.

Comment: True, and generally speaking, don't run `sed` on any binary file. Since `.git` is a dot file that is (typically) only found at the root dir, a simple solution is to change `find . -type f...` to `find * -type f ...`. But in any case, if there's any chance of binary files, either tailor the `find` as necessary, or don't use `find` at all.

Answer (score 7):

If you have access to Unix tools, you can run `diff` to find out which files lack a newline and then append it:

```
#!/bin/sh
for i
do
  if diff /dev/null "$i" | tail -1 | grep '^\\ No newline' > /dev/null
  then 
    echo >> "$i"
  fi
done
```

I'm relying on `diff` to produce the message with a  `\` in the first column, `tail` to give me the last line of `diff`'s output, and `grep` to tell me if the last line is the message I'm  looking for.  If all that works, then the `echo` produces a newline and the `>>` appends it to the file `"$i"`.  The quotes around `"$i"` make sure things still work if the filename has spaces in it.

Comment: Not bad, but grep returns a localized message, like "\Brak znaku nowej linii (etc.)". Besides, the diff outputs the whole file. I'd use `tail -1 $f | grep '\n'` for the condition (works on my box).

Comment: @TomaszGandor : 'tail -1 filename | grep '\n' seems to always return a false result on my mac regardless of whether there is a trailing newline or not..

Answer (score 4):

OK, after complaining in the comments, there is my better solution.
First, you want to know, which files are missing newlines:

```
find -type f -exec sh -c "tail -1 {} | xxd -p | tail -1 | grep -v 0a$" ';' -print
```

Not super fast (calling a couple of processes for each file), but it's OK for practical use.

Now, when you have it, you may as well add the newline, with another `-exec`:

```
find -type f -exec sh -c "tail -1 {} | xxd -p | tail -1 | grep -v 0a$" ';' -exec sh -c "echo >> {}" ';'
```

Possible gotchas:

- if filenames are bad, e.g. they have spaces, you may need `tail -1 \"{}\"`. 
  Or does find do it right?
- you may want to add more filtering to find, like `-name \*py`, or the like.
- think about possible DOS/Unix newlines mess before use (fix that first).

EDIT:

If you don't like the output from these commands (echoing some hex), add `-q` to grep:

```
find -type f -exec sh -c "tail -1 {} | xxd -p | tail -1 | grep -q -v 0a$" ';' -print
find -type f -exec sh -c "tail -1 {} | xxd -p | tail -1 | grep -q -v 0a$" ';' -exec sh -c "echo >> {}" ';'
```

Comment: This is *huge* overkill.

Answer (score 4):

```
tail -c1 file | read -r _ || echo >> file
```

gets the last character of the file pipes it into `read`, which will exit with a nonzero exit code if it encounters EOF before newline (so, if the last character of the file isn't a newline).  If `read` exits nonzero, then append a newline onto the file using `echo` (if `read` exits 0, that satisfies the `||`, so the `echo` command isn't run).

From http://backreference.org/2010/05/23/sanitizing-files-with-no-trailing-newline/.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me in `ansible`

Answer (score 3):

Try ex-way:

```
ex -s +"bufdo wq" *.c
```

And recursively (with [a new globbing option](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/globstar-new-bash-globbing-option) enabled):

```
ex -s +"bufdo wq" **/*.c
```

This is equivalent to `vi -es`. Change `*.c` to extension of your interest.

The `ex`/`vi` would automatically append newline on save if it's not present.

Answer (score 2):

Using awk :

```
awk '/^$/{f=1}END{ if (!f) {print "\r"}}1' inputfile
```

Match blank line `^$`(just like you did) and set up a flag. If flag is not set at the end, place newline character.

Note: that `\r` is in OS X. Use `\n` for other.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `vi` or `ex`:

```
ex -scwq foo.txt
```

or for multiple files:

```
vi -es +"bufdo wq" *.txt
ex -s +"bufdo wq" *.txt
```

which automatically adds EOL at EOF on file save if it's missing.

To apply for certain files recursively, use [a new globbing option](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/globstar-new-bash-globbing-option) (`**`) such as `**/*.txt` (enable by `shopt -s globstar`).

Answer (score 2):

I'm surprised nobody has mentioned that many simple text-processing tools like Awk will add a newline as a side effect.  Here is a simple loop which will overwrite a file only if a newline was actually added.

```
for f in *; do
    awk 1 "$f" >tmp
    cmp -s tmp "$f" || mv tmp "$f"
done
rm -f tmp
```

(The temporary file is obviously a bit of a wart.)

IDEone demo: http://ideone.com/HpRHcx

Answer (score 2):

**Using Bash only**

You can use Command Substitution (remove trailing newlines) with Here Strings (appends newline):

```
   Command Substitution
       Command substitution allows the output of a command to replace the command  name.   There  are  two
       forms:

          $(command)
       or
          `command`

       Bash  performs  the expansion by executing command in a subshell environment and replacing the com-
       mand substitution with the standard output of the command,  with  any  trailing  newlines  deleted.
       Embedded newlines are not deleted, but they may be removed during word splitting.  The command sub-
       stitution $(cat file) can be replaced by the equivalent but faster $(< file).



   Here Strings
       A variant of here documents, the format is:

          [n]<<<word

       The word undergoes brace expansion, tilde expansion, parameter and variable expansion, command sub-
       stitution,  arithmetic expansion, and quote removal.  Pathname expansion and word splitting are not
       performed.  The result is supplied as a single string, with a newline appended, to the  command  on
       its standard input (or file descriptor n if n is specified).
```

Here's how it works:

```
cat <<<"$(<inputfile)"
```

Output to file:

```
cat <<<"$(<inputfile)" >outputfile
```

If you need `inputfile` and `outputfile` to be the same file name, you have a couple options - use `sponge` command, save to temporary variable with more command substitution, or save to temporary file.

---

**Using Sed**

Others have suggested using

```
sed '$a\' inputfile
```

which appends nothing to the last line. This is fine, but I think

```
sed '$q' inputfile
```

is a bit clearer, because it quits on the last line. Or you can do

```
sed -n 'p'
```

which uses `-n` to suppress output, but prints it back out with `p`.

In any of these cases, `sed` will fix up the line and add a newline, at least for GNU and BSD sed. However, I'm not sure if this functionality is defined by POSIX. A version of `sed` might just skip your line without a newline since a line is defined as

> [A sequence of zero or more non- <newline> characters plus a terminating <newline> character.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_205)

Answer (score 1):

`` find -type f | while read f; do [[ `tail -c1 "$f"` ]] && echo >> "$f"; done ``

I'm using `find` instead of `for f in *` as it is recursive and the question was about "huge number of source files".

I'm using `while read` instead of `find -exec` or `xargs` for performance reasons, it saves spawning shell process every time.

I'm taking advantage of the fact that backtick operator is returning output of command "with any trailing newlines deleted" `man bash`, so for properly terminated files backtick will be empty and echo will be skipped.

The `find | read` couple will fail on filenames that contain newlines, but it's easy to fix if required:

`` find -type f -print0 | while read -d $'\0' f; do [[ `tail -c1 "$f"` ]] && echo >> "$f"; done ``

Answer (score 1):

Below is my bash script solution. It first checks that the file is a text file. Then, if it's a text file, it uses tail and od (octal dump) to see if the last character is the newline character. If it isn't, then it appends a newline using echo:

```
item="$1"

if file "$item" | egrep '\btext\b' > /dev/null
then
    if ! tail -c 1 "$item" | od -b -A n | egrep '\b012\b' > /dev/null
    then
        echo "(appending final newline to ${item})"
        echo >> "$item"
    fi
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

In case it is of use, something like this usually works for me:

```
printf "%s\n" "$(cat file_that_MIGHT_need_a_NL.txt)"
```

It is not the most elegant solution, but it allows me to use tools like `sed`, `grep`, etc. instead of just `cat` in there.

Of course any valid variable or string should work also.

YMMV

Answer (score 0):

Due To command localization Tim and Norman answer Shall be improved using 'LANG=C' prefix to have a chance to match 'No newline' pattern with every system having any regional parameters

This ensures an ending empty line to every file put on the command line of this script :

```
 #!/bin/sh -f
 for i in $* ; do  echo $i; \
 if LANG=C diff /dev/null "$i" | tail -1 | \
  grep '^\\ No newline' > /dev/null; then echo >> "$i"; \
 fi; done
```

And this script detects files lacking of it :

```
 #!/bin/sh -f
 for i in $* ; do \
 if LANG=C diff /dev/null "$i" | tail -1 | \
  grep '^\\ No newline' > /dev/null; then  echo $i; \
 fi; done
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this task by using `dos2unix` (or counterparts) with the `--newline` flag. The advantage is that these tools detect binary files on their own. I like the solution with `tail -c1` but filtering binary files beforehand has been *really* slow for me.

```
dos2unix --newline my_file.txt
```

Eventually I wrote a script that searched my project directory, converted all files to `LF` (`dos2unix`) except `*.cmd` files (`CRLF`, `unix2dos`) and used the flag to get the newlines right with one call.

Comment: I've tested the command, but somehow it doesn't work (at least on OS X). Testing: `printf foo > foo.txt && dos2unix --newline foo.txt && wc foo.txt` which gives me `0 1 3` which is not correct.

Comment: I can confirm that this doesn't work on Debian Linux. I recall doing this successfully in Cygwin back then.

Answer (score 0):

After finding the tool do this job with no luck. I decide to write my own

This is my python script to do that job

It only append (\r\n) to file not contains (\n) at the end of file

https://github.com/tranhuanltv/append_newline

Usage: append_newline.py .c ./projects ./result_dir

Make Pull Requests if you want to

Comment: This is very questionable - the seek to -1 from END is OK, but you could easily mix Unix and DOS newlines this way...

Answer (score 0):

```
pcregrep --recursive --exclude-dir=.git \
  --files-without-match --multiline '\n\z' . |
  while read k ; do echo >> "$k"; done
```

There are several steps involved here:

1. Recursively find files
2. Detect which files lack a trailing new line
3. Loop over each of those files
4. Append the newline

Step 1 is traditionally done with `find` (following the Unix tradition of 
"each tool doing one thing and doing it well"), but since pcregrep has builtin support, I'm comfortable using it.  I'm careful to avoid messing around with the .git folder.

Step 2 is done with a multiline regular expression matching files that *do* have a final newline, and printing the names of files that *don't* match.

Step 3 is done with a while/read loop rather than a for/in, since the latter fails for filenames with spaces and for extremely long lists of files.

Step 4 is a simple echo, following @norman-ramsey's approach.

h/t @anthony-bush https://stackoverflow.com/a/20687956/577438 for the pcregrep suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

An elegant solution exists using standard shell commands:

```
tail -c 1 file.txt | read || echo >> file.txt
```

1. `tail` Outputs the last byte of file
2. `read` Reads a line into a variable. With no variable specified, does nothing, but if an EOF occurs before a newline, exits with code 1.
3. `echo` Runs only if read fails (i.e. if the last character was not a newline), and appends a newline to `file.txt`

Comment: With no variable, `read` will populate `$REPLY` variable, by default. If you really want to ignore read input, you could use `_` variable: `read _`.