# Add new line character at the end of file in bash

Tags: bash, file, command, newline

How can I use bash command line to add new line character at the end of file named `file.txt`.
I tried use `echo` but it's not right. Can you show me how can I do it?

Comment: see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31947/how-to-add-a-newline-to-the-end-of-a-file

Answer (score 119):

```
echo "" >> file.txt
```

Adds a newline character at the end

Comment: Extremely simple and extremely fast, even on very large files. `>>` seems to always be fast for appending.

Comment: `echo >> file.txt` works too, you don't need the `""` part.

Answer (score 21):

With `sed`:

```
sed -i '' -e '$a\' file.txt
```

with `echo`:

```
echo  >> file.txt
```

Comment: I don't think that `awk` one is right. That will create a file for each line of `file.txt` that is named after the contents of that line, and containing a single newline...

Comment: `sed -i '$a\' file.txt` is sufficient

Comment: @CervEd `-i ''` is for Mac users, `-i` for everyone else

Comment: has sed on os x 13.4 changed? I cannot get this to work.

Answer (score 4):

Use Vi which automatically creates EOL at EOF on file save.

For example:

```
vi -escwq foo.txt
```

or:

```
ex -scwq foo.txt
```

To correct multiple files, check: [How to fix 'No newline at end of file' for lots of files?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30276797/55075) at SO

Answer (score 4):

> GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin14)

```
echo \ >> file.txt
```

Comment: That adds a space character as well as a line-feed character.

Comment: ah yes, you're right.  It appends the space to the line before the new line.  Good catch.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me.

```
sed -i -z 's/$/\n/g' file.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

This works on centos the empty string above didn't.

```
sed -i -e '$a\' file
```