# Stitching together multiple chapters, each with a % header

Tags: markdown, pandoc

I have some Markdown files, each using `%` syntax to set their title, e.g.

```
% A nice chapter

Lorum ipsum ....

# First section

Blah blah
```

If I compile them one-by-one to HTML, these chapter headings become page titles which is exactly what I'd like.

However, I would like to use the same input files to also generate a single PDF, with a table of contents. So I tried

```
$ pandoc --toc -o full.pdf a.md b.md
```

However, the output of this is not at all what I would like:

- The `%` heading from the first file (`a.md`) becomes the document title
- Subsequent `%` headings are ignored
- `#` headings show up as chapter headings in the TOC, but they don't look like chapters at all (they don't even start on a new page).

**How do I assemble Markdown files containing chapters into a single book?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@mb21's suggestion is to use `#` for chapter titles, i.e. shift everything by one level. With that, `pandoc --top-level-division=chapter --toc` indeed does the right thing, but then the same files don't work as nicely with the HTML backend: if I don't have a `%` title, it complains

```
[WARNING] This document format requires a nonempty <title> element.
  Please specify either 'title' or 'pagetitle' in the metadata,
  e.g. by using --metadata pagetitle="..." on the command line.
  Falling back to 'a'
```

So seemingly we have a conundrum where either the HTML output is correct or the PDF one, but not both at the same time.

The solution is to store files with `%` for the (chapter) title and `#` for the top sections etc. (i.e. HTML-compatible format), and then transform them to PDF-compatible format on the fly. The Makefile rule I ended up writing is:

```
RetroClash.pdf: $(MARKDOWNS)
    ($(foreach MARKDOWN, $^, sed -e '$$a\\' -e 's/^#/##/' -e 's/^% /# /' $(MARKDOWN);)) | \
    pandoc --top-level-division=chapter --toc --toc-depth=2 -o $@
```

The first line goes through each input `.md` file, and transforms it as such:

- [Adds a newline to the end of each file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23056914/477476) to ensure each chapter title is on a new paragraph
- Shifts down each `#` heading by one, i.e. transforms `#` to `##`, `##` to `###` and so on
- Replaces `%` heading with `#`

Then the concatenation of all transformed Markdown files are passed to Pandoc as a single input.

Comment: Note that this doesn't handle gracefully situations where you have code blocks containing `#` on the first column, such as a shell script with comments.

Answer (score 1):

Pandoc's `%` syntax is actually for [document titles](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#metadata-blocks). Pandoc only operates on one document per conversion (so if you have multiple input files, they will basically be concatenated before processing).

What you could do instead, is use headings:

```
# title one
```

together with setting [top-level-division](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#option--top-level-division) to `chapter` or even `part`:

```
pandoc --top-level-division=chapter --toc -o full.pdf a.md b.md
```

Comment: This doesn't play well with the HTML output, though: "[WARNING] This document format requires a nonempty `<title>` element.
  Please specify either `title` or `pagetitle` in the metadata,
  e.g. by using `--metadata pagetitle="..."` on the command line."

Comment: well, that would be the book title, which you would just set on the first chapter (or on the command line). see also the `--shift-heading-level-by` option...

Comment: I meant the HTML output *per chapter*. See my eventual solution which incorporates yours but keeps standalone chapter files to use `%`.