# How can I add a trailing newline to files that don't have it?

Tags: replace, newline

I have a Git project that contains a lot of files with no trailing newline.  I want to add trailing newlines without adding superfluous newlines.  How can I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add a newline only if it doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10082204/add-a-newline-only-if-it-doesnt-exist)

Comment: That question is informative, but addresses the case of only one file.

Comment: Trivially, add [Execute command on all files in a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523415/execute-command-on-all-files-in-a-directory)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this surprisingly tricky to do using the tools I would usually use (`grep`, `sed`), but an elegant solution does exist using standard shell commands:

```
tail -c 1 file.txt | read || echo >> file.txt
```

1. `tail` Outputs the last byte of file
2. `read` Reads a line into a variable. With no variable specified, does nothing, but if an EOF occurs before a newline, exits with code 1.
3. `echo` Runs only if read fails (i.e. if the last character was not a newline), and appends a newline to `file.txt`

#### To find the files we want to change you can use `find`:

```
find -not -path "./.git/*" -type f -exec sh -c "grep -Iq . {} && (tail -c 1 {} | read || echo >> {})" \;
```

1. `-not -path` excludes `.git/`, which we don't want to mess with
2. `-type f` restricts the search to files
3. `-exec sh -c "..."` is required to bundle together commands that include pipes
4. `grep -Iq .` searches for anything (`.`) so is a no-op, but exits with code 1 if file is binary
5. `{}` marks the position where `find` will insert the file name

#### I would advise checking the list of files before running the command.  Do this by replacing `echo >> {}` with `echo {}`:

```
find -not -path "./.git/*" -type f -exec sh -c "grep -Iq . {} && (tail -c 1 {} | read || echo {})" \;
```