# Add newline to all files that don't already have one

Tags: bash

I made a mistake in my .editorconfig definition and forgot to add

`insert_final_newline = true`

So now some files do have a newline at the end while some do not.

I found similar questions such as:

- [How can I add a trailing newline to files that don't have it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40046039/how-can-i-add-a-trailing-newline-to-files-that-dont-have-it)
- https://serverfault.com/questions/339827/sed-add-new-line-to-every-file-that-does-not-have-one-at-end-of-file

However the solutions provided there add a newline to *all* files. I need to only add it to those that don't have a final newline already.

EDIT: The question that was linked as answering mine question doesn't do so as the answers are for single file only. I need this recursively for all files. Voting to reopen.

Comment: BTW: I posted an answer, BUT I now see that the first answer you linked to, also solves the problem (in a slightly different way).

Comment: It doesn't. As I noted it adds a newline to all files, not just the ones missing it.

Comment: This is simply not true. I just tried it: See [here](https://user.fm/files/v2-cee1a86777e38268432cdd09b515a9eb/capture_20221110_092847.jpg). If it does not work for you, I would be curious to see a screenshot which demonstrates your point.

Comment: Which command are you using exactly? I tried multiple from the linked questions but all had the issue I described.

Comment: Did you have a look at the sceenshot which I posted? It shows the command I used.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE** : I updated this solution to accomodate the comment by Paul Hodges:

Just test, whether the last character in a file is a newline:

```
if [[ -z $(tail -c 1 YOUR_FILE) && ! -s YOUR_FILE ]]
then
  # File ends in a newline, don't add one
else
  # No newline in file, or file empty - add a newline
fi
```

Explanation:

If a file ends in a newline, `tail -c 1` will return this newline character, but command substition will remove it. Therefore `$(tail -c 1 ...)` will be empty. However, if the file itself is empty, the `$(tail ...)` will also be empty. Therefore we need a check for the file being not-empty (`! -s ...` ).

Comment: This was my first thought too, but in Git Bash it isn't working as I expected.

Comment: "isn't working" is not an accurate error description. It should work in any bash implementation new enough to support `$'...'`, and where you have `tail` in your path - both conditions are easy to check, so if you still encounter problems, you need to provide debugging details.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10082466/8656552 addresses it.

Comment: Both this and the linked answer only solve the case of single file. How do I use this for all files?

Comment: @enumag : You write a loop  which goes over all files. If you don't know how to write a loop in bash, please ask a new question, because on Stackoverflow, each question should focus on exactly one programming problem.

Comment: I'd rather use a one liner than a script though.

Comment: You can write the whole script into a single line. Just separate the statements by semicolon instead of a newline.

Comment: @PaulHodges: Thanks for pointing this out. I have updated my answer. Could you check it for correctness?