# How to add newline character at the end of many files

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I've a lot of PHP files and I'd like to fix newline character after the last line (if not present) with a bash script.

Is there any command to to that easily?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Short and quick [tee](/questions/tagged/tee)

But adding a *newline* at end of **each** files. For strictly adding a *newline* at end of files where there are not, please go to second part of this answer!

#### `tee` is the tool you're searching for:

Simply:

```
tee -a <<<'' file1 file2 ...
```

or

```
find /path -type f ! -empty -name '*.php' -exec tee -a <<<'' {} +
```

**Warning:** Don't miss `-a` option!

It's very quick, but add a newline on each files.

(You could whipe in a second command like `sed '${/^$/d}' -i file1 file2 ...` all empty last lines in all files. ;)

(**Warning again:** I insist: if you miss `-a` flag for `tee` command, this will shortly and quickly **replace** the content of each file found by a *newline*!! So **all** your files will become *empty*!)

#### Some explanation:

from `man tee`:

> ```
> NAME
>        tee - read from standard input and write to standard output and files
>
> SYNOPSIS
>        tee [OPTION]... [FILE]...
>
> DESCRIPTION
>        Copy standard input to each FILE, and also to standard output.
>
>        -a, --append
>               append to the given FILEs, do not overwrite
> ```

- So `tee` will reproduce, *appending* (because of option `a`), to each *file* submited as argument, what become on *standard input*.
- [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) feature: "*`here strings`*" (see `man -Pless\ +/Here.Strings bash`), you could use `command <<<"here string""` in replacement of  `echo "here string"| command`. For this, bash add a *newline* to submited string (even empty string: `<<<''`).

## Slower, but stronger

> fix newline character after the last line (if not present)

Stay very quick because of limited forks, but one fork to `tail -c1` have to be done for each files anyway!

```
while IFS= read -d '' -r file
do
    IFS= read -d "" chr < <(
        exec tail -c1 "$file"
    )
    if [[ $chr != $'\n' ]]
    then
        echo >> "$file"
    fi   
done < <(
    find . -type f ! -empty -name '*.php' -print0
)
```

Could by written more compact:

```
while IFS= read -d '' -r file; do
    IFS= read -d "" chr < <( exec tail -c1 "$file" )
    [[ $chr != $'\n' ]] && echo >> "$file"
done < <( find . -type f ! -empty -name '*.php' -print0 )
```

- `find -print0` print each filename separated by a null character `\0`.
- `IFS= read -d '' -r file` don't consider *special characters* nor *spaces*, so *`$file`* could hold any kind of filename, event containing spaces or accented characters.
- `exec` tell bash to execute `tail` as subprocess, avoid *default* second fork running `tail` in a `subsubprocess`.
- `tail -c1` read last caracter of `$file`
- `IFS= read -d "" chr` store last caracter into `$chr` variable.

Comment: What about only adding the new line if there is no empty line at end of the file?

Comment: @AlecRust The last command check **each** found file by using `tail -c1` for adding *newline* only where there are not!

Answer (score 1):

Loop through all files (you can use find) and check with tail last character by read (if it is new line - for windows new line you can add \r\n, and if read returns 0, echo new line to this file

```
for i in *.php; do
    tail -c1 ${i} | read -r \n || echo '' >> ${i}
done
```