# bash: check if gzipped files end with new line character and add if missing

Tags: bash

I see variations of this question asked in other posts but cannot find an answer for gzipped files.

I have a several very large gzipped files, some of which do not end in a new line character. I'd like to use bash to check each of my files for whether they end in a new line character. If the new line character is missing at the end of a file I'd like to add it. I see from this post ([Add a newline only if it doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10082204/add-a-newline-only-if-it-doesnt-exist)) that I can add a new line to files using this:

```
[[ $(tail -c1 file) && -f file ]]&&echo ''>>file
```

But this doesn't work for gzipped files. Any suggestions for working with gzipped files? Thanks!

Comment: zcat can be used to output the compressed file.

Comment: Check your echo with ```help echo``` - My favourite options are ```-ne``` for explizit newline: ```echo -ne '\n'``` - And a opened logfile i make totally empty with: ```echo -n >logfile```

Comment: @koyaanisqatsi thanks! I've modified my code to: `[[ $(tail -c1 file) && -f file ]]&&echo -ne '\n' >> file`       But it doesn't add the new line to a gzipped file (though works for uncompressed file), I must be missing something?

Comment: You have to check if gzipped then ```&&``` do something else ```||``` do something else - Like this: ```zchk() { ( ( zcat ${1} &>/dev/null ) && ( printf "%s\n" "${1} is gz" ) || ( cat ${1} ) ) }``` - This is a function definition execute it after defining in bash or script with: ```zchk filename.z``` or/and ```zchk filename```