# Substring Detection not able to detect newline

Tags: bash, shell, file, io, scripting

My code goes over a text file and does some work on it. I'm having trouble with dealing with (lack of ) newlines in the end. I want to test if the line has a newline at the end a line. If it does I want to add a newline to the file's line. Right now, my code is not adding any new lines at all, and I'm not quite sure why.

Have Googled but nothing is working.

```
while read line || [ -n "$line" ]; do
 ...#Do things
        SUB="\n"
        if [[ "$line" =~ .*"$SUB".* ]]; then
            echo "It's there."
            printf "\n" >> $DEC
        fi
done <ip.txt
```

I can only use bash (no sed, awk etc.).

I want:

Case 1:

ip:

```
Line1 (\n here)
Line2 (\n here)
Line3(no \n here)
```

Output:

```
line1 (\n here)
line2 (\n here)
line3 (no \n here)
```

Case 2:

ip:

```
Line1 (\n here)
Line2(\n here)
Line3(\n here)
```

Output:

```
line1 (\n here)
line2 (\n here)
line3 (\n here)
```

But I get:

```
line1(no space)line2(no space)line3
```

For both cases

Comment: not sure I understand the objective, nor how you'd expect to match on a 'newline' character in the middle of a line (`"$line" =~ .*"$SUB".*`) so fwiw ... `SUB="\n"` is going to assign a 2-character string to `SUB` ... the characters '\' and 'n'; to assign a newline character try `SUB=$'\n'`

Comment: I don't expect to. After all the Google solutions for newlines weren't working, I just checked for substring detection. Figured it should work

Comment: @markp-fuso the sub you gave me doesn't work. It doesn't get detected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems with your current method. The first is that `read` removes the newline from the end of lines, so you can't check the result for newline -- it won't be there. `read` will return an error status if it hits end-of-file rather than a newline, which is why you need `|| [ -n "$line" ]` to keep the loop from just exiting when reading an unterminated line.

The second problem is that `SUB="\n"` stores a backslash and an "n" in the variable; to get a newline, use `SUB=$'\n'`.

Depending on what else you're trying to do in the loop, there are a number of options. If adding a missing newline to the end of the file is the only goal, there are a bunch of options in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10082204/add-a-newline-only-if-it-doesnt-exist).

If you need to read through the lines, process them in the shell, and then output them with the missing newline added at the end, then just use your current loop, and output each line with a newline -- you need to add it whether or not it was there originally, and if you *always* add it, it'll always be there.

If you need to explicitly find out whether the last line had a newline and do something different if it did, one option is to modify your original code a little:

```
while read line; do
    # process lines that had newlines at the end
done <ip.txt
if [ -n "$line" ]; then
    # final line was missing a newline; process it here
fi
```

Another option is to read the entire file into an array (each line as an array entry), since `mapfile` doesn't remove the line terminators (unless you specifically ask it to with `-t`):

```
mapfile ipArray <ip.txt
for line in "${foo[@]}"; do
    if [[ "$line" = *$'\n' ]]; then
        # Process line with newline at end
        cleanLine="${line%$'\n'}"    # If you need the line *without* newline
    else
        # Process line without newline
    fi
done
```

Comment: You are quick! Had just tested `while read line; do i=1; done < <(printf "one\ntwo\nthree"); [ -n "$line" ] && echo "newline needed for $line"` and looked up and you beat me `:)`