# Bash Script: Append text to a file, on a new line?

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to write a public SSH key I have in a variable, and append it to the authorized_keys SSH file (`~/.ssh/authorized_keys`). The problem is, its not adding it to a new line.

I'm ending up with something like below from `cat ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`, all on a single line:

```
ssh-rsa ... original@hostssh-rsa ... root@anotherhost
```

Shell

```
sudo echo $SSH_KEY >> $SSH_AUTHORIZED_KEYS_FILE
```

How can I ensure this isn't going to break things?

Comment: It sounds like the original file is missing the newline it's supposed to have at the end. If that's the problem, see ["Add a newline only if it doesn't exist"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10082204/add-a-newline-only-if-it-doesnt-exist).

Comment: You can't use `sudo` and `echo` and `>>` as the `>>` won't be done with super-user privilege. In your case if there is no `'\n'` in the `$SSH_KEY` var just use `printf`, e.g. `printf "%s\n" $SSH_KEY >> authorized_keys` OR if it is the lack of a `'\n'` at the end of the existing `authorized_keys` file, then `printf "\n%s\n" $SSH_KEY >> authorized_keys`

Comment: Did you consider using `ssh-copy-id`?

Comment: In addition to what Gordon Davisson said: It is a good idea to **always** ensure that a text file ends in a final newline character. Many tools ignore the last "line" of a file if it is not properly terminated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use echo with the -e option (which enables interpretation of backslash escapes) and prepend "\n" to what you're trying to append to the file. This first writes a newline character to the file, followed by the value of your variable.

```
echo -e "\n$SSH_KEY" >> $SSH_AUTHORIZED_KEYS_FILE
```

Please note that running echo without the -n option will automatically put another newline at the end of your output. If you want to prevent this, write:

```
echo -ne "\n$SSH_KEY" >> $SSH_AUTHORIZED_KEYS_FILE
```

Comment: While `echo -e` is reliable as long as you are sure you are using Bash, there is still absolutely no reason to prefer it over the robust, POSIX standard, portable, versatile `printf`.

Comment: You should never want to not write the final newline when writing to a text file, as this makes it no longer a valid text file.

Comment: `echo -e` isn't even consistent in bash, it depends on whether it's in POSIX mode (due to `set -o posix`, or `POSIXLY_CORRECT` being set, or an equivalent compile-time option, or...). I strongly recommend using `printf` (as in `printf '\n%s\n' "$SSH_KEY"`) instead.